# What's the joke in Voldemort's words?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), wounded Neville limping towards Voldermort:

> Voldemort: Well, I must say I'd hoped for better.
>
> (*People laugh*)

What's the joke in Voldemort's words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voldemort is belittling Neville.  This is part of pattern of bullying behaviour by various Slytherins towards Neville that has been repeated over the series, yet we know that Neville has hidden strength and courage.

The death eaters laugh in the same way that a gang of friends laugh at insults made by a lead bully.